# Eclipse or Spring Tool Suite 4 installation problem in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, eclipse

Recently I upgraded to Ubuntu 20.04 from 18.04. After that while installing Eclipse or Spring Tool Suite 4, after extraction when clicking on the installer I am getting below error -

"There is no application installed for executable files".

The process used to work seamlessly with Ubuntu 18.04. I am wondering what could be missing in the latest Ubuntu version?

Comment: Hi! Does it work if you try opening the terminal, dragging the the executable file into it and pressing enter?

Comment: Do you have execution right on the installer file ? Do you have Java installed on your computer ?